# Stream methods make a loop internally?

Tags: java, loops, java-stream

I am studying the streams API for Java and from what I see,is highly recommend that I use several methods to change a collection with a stream, besides it is very good that with this api I stop using loops, but I was wondering, each method of a stream does not perform the necessary loops internment? Doesn't it end up being detrimental to the performance (of applications that demand a good performance) that I use stream? In many cases I could make more than one necessary modification to the collection in just one loop.

But I also imagine that the developers of JDK and JVM also performed their black magic to prevent this. If so, what are the details of this magic?

Comment: It's not highly recommended to use stream each time you have a loop, sometimes it's a very bad idea and the loop are lot easier and more performant ;)

Comment: Horrible materials that I am seeing then.
What I see most in these materials are many nested methods of streams

Comment: A stream can do much more than a simple loop. It can use spliterators and things and also easily process the data in parallel, multithreaded. However, factor number one is readability, not performance. In some situations a stream is much more readable. Even if its maybe some nanoseconds slower, you usually want to prefer that. And in other situations streams are just horrible to read, for example if you have really nested and complex setups. Then prefer a classic loop. Optimize for readability first.

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek can you add this comment as a answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each method in stream API does not create a new loop... it combines methods and executes them in single loop once it hits termination method (like `collect`).
From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

> Stream operations are divided into intermediate and terminal
>   operations, and are combined to form stream pipelines. A stream
>   pipeline consists of a source (such as a Collection, an array, a
>   generator function, or an I/O channel); followed by zero or more
>   intermediate operations such as Stream.filter or Stream.map; and a
>   terminal operation such as Stream.forEach or Stream.reduce.
>
> Processing streams lazily allows for significant efficiencies; in a
>   pipeline such as the filter-map-sum example above, filtering, mapping,
>   and summing **can be fused into a single pass on the data**, with minimal
>   intermediate state. Laziness also allows avoiding examining all the
>   data when it is not necessary; for operations such as "find the first
>   string longer than 1000 characters", it is only necessary to examine
>   just enough strings to find one that has the desired characteristics
>   without examining all of the strings available from the source. (This
>   behavior becomes even more important when the input stream is infinite
>   and not merely large.)

The only method that creates new loop is `flatMap`.

Other than that, yes streams are slower, but not by much. They are far easier to read, write, modify though. And to add to that, they are encourage immutability, which is a trade-off of performance for less buggy code.